# Trying to implement an opacity control for a MapTiler map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm following this guide http://www.gavinharriss.com/code/opacity-control to implement an opacity control slider with a MapTiler map, however, I can't figure out the correct function to link to all the tiles.

The section I am trying to change is this:

```
CustomTileOverlay.prototype.getTileUrl = function (coord, zoom) {
    // Restricting tiles to the small tile set we have in the example
    if (zoom == 13 && coord.x >= 8004 && coord.x <= 8006 && coord.y >= 3013 && coord.y <= 3015) {
        return "tiles/" + zoom + "-" + coord.x + "-" + coord.y + ".png";
    }
    else {
        return "tiles/blanktile.png";
    }
}
```

The hierarchy of the tiles looks like this (Each number 13-17 is a zoom level).

[image: Tiles Hierachry]

I tried using the code that calls the original overlay, but I'm not thinking it's correct.

```
CustomTileOverlay.prototype.getTileUrl = function(coord, zoom) { 
        var proj = map.getProjection();
        var z2 = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        var tileXSize = 256 / z2;
        var tileYSize = 256 / z2;
        var tileBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(coord.x * tileXSize, (coord.y + 1) * tileYSize)),
            proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * tileXSize, coord.y * tileYSize))
        );
        var y = coord.y;
        var x = coord.x >= 0 ? coord.x : z2 + coord.x
        if (mapBounds.intersects(tileBounds) && (mapMinZoom <= zoom) && (zoom <= mapMaxZoom))
            return zoom + "/" + x + "/" + y + ".png";
        else
            return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
    }
```

My code looks like this for the entire map file if that helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCjb3ppOC4EegwpoOuJ-hgjfjXYDVuTz9M&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ExtDraggableObject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CustomTileOverlay.js"></script>


<script>


var map;
var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.439157, -117.732699),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.499760, -117.644040));
var mapMinZoom = 13;
var mapMaxZoom = 17;
var maptiler = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) { 
        var proj = map.getProjection();
        var z2 = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        var tileXSize = 256 / z2;
        var tileYSize = 256 / z2;
        var tileBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(coord.x * tileXSize, (coord.y + 1) * tileYSize)),
            proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * tileXSize, coord.y * tileYSize))
        );
        var y = coord.y;
        var x = coord.x >= 0 ? coord.x : z2 + coord.x
        if (mapBounds.intersects(tileBounds) && (mapMinZoom <= zoom) && (zoom <= mapMaxZoom))
            return zoom + "/" + x + "/" + y + ".png";
        else
            return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true,

    opacity: 1.0
});

</script>


<script>

// MAP OPTIONS //

var OPACITY_MAX_PIXELS = 57; // Width of opacity control image
var overlay;

function init() {
    var opts = {
        tilt:0,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.469469, -117.688360),
        zoom: 13,
        maxZoom: 17,

    };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);
  map.setMapTypeId('satellite');
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, maptiler);



/// AutoComplete ///


  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
  document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });



  /// Opacity ///

  var initialOpacity = 40;

  overlay = new CustomTileOverlay(map, initialOpacity);
  overlay.show();

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
    overlay.deleteHiddenTiles(map.getZoom());
  });

  // Add opacity control and set initial value
  createOpacityControl(map, initialOpacity);


}


function createOpacityControl(map, opacity) {
      var sliderImageUrl = "opacity-slider3d14.png";

      // Create main div to hold the control.
      var opacityDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
      opacityDiv.setAttribute("style", "margin:5px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;background:url(" + sliderImageUrl + ") no-repeat;width:71px;height:21px;cursor:pointer;");

      // Create knob
      var opacityKnobDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
      opacityKnobDiv.setAttribute("style", "padding:0;margin:0;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;background:url(" + sliderImageUrl + ") no-repeat -71px 0;width:14px;height:21px;");
      opacityDiv.appendChild(opacityKnobDiv);

      var opacityCtrlKnob = new ExtDraggableObject(opacityKnobDiv, {
        restrictY: true,
        container: opacityDiv
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(opacityCtrlKnob, "dragend", function () {
        setOpacity(opacityCtrlKnob.valueX());
      });

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(opacityDiv, "click", function (e) {
        var left = findPosLeft(this);
        var x = e.pageX - left - 5; // - 5 as we're using a margin of 5px on the div
        opacityCtrlKnob.setValueX(x);
        setOpacity(x);
      });

      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(opacityDiv);

      // Set initial value
      var initialValue = OPACITY_MAX_PIXELS / (100 / opacity);
      opacityCtrlKnob.setValueX(initialValue);
      setOpacity(initialValue);
    }

    function setOpacity(pixelX) {
      // Range = 0 to OPACITY_MAX_PIXELS
      var value = (100 / OPACITY_MAX_PIXELS) * pixelX;
      if (value < 0) value = 0;
      if (value == 0) {
        if (overlay.visible == true) {
          overlay.hide();
        }
      }
      else {
        overlay.setOpacity(value);
        if (overlay.visible == false) {
          overlay.show();
        }
      }
    }

    function findPosLeft(obj) {
      var curleft = 0;
      if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
          curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return curleft;
      }
      return undefined;
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);


</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">

<div id="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any guidance would be appreciated since obviously I'm not a javascript dev. Thank You

Comment: Can you provide a full url to one of the tiles that you're trying to reach please. I'm wondering if the urls you're generating are valid? You can use the Chrome developer tools to watch network requests and see why they might be failing as well (could be something simple).

Comment: You can also use the Chrome developer tools to add a breakpoint on the CustomTileOverlay.prototype.getTileUrl code and step though line by line to see what is happening. Might also be quite revealing.

Comment: Yah sure, here is a URL http://wrongplatform.com/demo/17/22670/52578.png

Comment: Trying to debug now

Comment: I'm getting a lot of these errors "GET http://wrongplatform.com/demo/13/1416/3287.png 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Your error for hitting http://wrongplatform.com/demo/13/1416/3287.png directly states "Error establishing a database connection". So I guess the issue is something unrelated to the client side javascript. Something server side is trying to connect to your database but can't.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I uploaded it to a new server with no errors but it still isn't working. Gunna keep messing with it. Any ideas about the function I'm using?

Comment: Not sure, I tried to take a look at what you published at http://wrongplatform.com/demo/ but I only see issues due to database connection. Nothing wrong client side as far as I can tell. Fix the database issue / remove it from the equation and I'll have another look if you want.

Comment: Ok try it here. thank you for all the help.
http://sorrysloth.com/demodemo/googlemaps.html

Comment: In your CustomTileOverlay.prototype.getTileUrl logic you always return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png", you never hit the return zoom + "/" + x + "/" + y + ".png"; line of code so I guess your logic is a little out. You can use the Chrome browser to debug your javascript. Open the "Sources" tab, find your code and set breakpoints so you can step through the code line by line and see what's happening.